# matlab creating paths to stop copying code

Tags: matlab

I have created a few general function in MATLAB that I intend to use for a few separate projects. However I do not want to copy the function into each separate project function.

I have created a folder called Misc_Function when I have placed these general functions. I know I can reference this functions explicitly by using the path and function name when trying to call the functions.

I believe you can add a path (in my case 'H:\MyTeam\Matlab\Misc_Function') when MATLAB loads up is that correct and if so how do you do this?

Assuming the above can be done I'm interested to know how MATLAB finds the correct function. In my understanding (guess work) MATLAB has a list of paths that it check trying to find a function with the name specified - is that correct? If so what happens when there are functions with the same name?

Comment: For the last question - The one residing in the path that is higher up on the paths list is chosen. For adding path(s), you can use `addpath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB indeed has its own [search path](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/search-path.html) which is a collection of folders that MATLAB will search when you reference a function or class (and a few other things). To see the search path, type `path` at the MATLAB prompt. From the [documentation:](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html)

> The *order* of folders on the search path is important. When files with the same name appear in multiple folders on the search path, MATLAB uses the one found in the folder nearest to the top of the search path.

If you have a set of utility functions that you want to make available to your projects, add the folder to the top of the search path with the [addpath](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) function, like so

```
addpath('H:\MyTeam\Matlab\Misc_Function');
```

You have to do this everytime you start MATLAB. Alternatively, and more conveniently, save the current search path with the [savepath](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/savepath.html) command or add the above commands to your [startup.m](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the actual paths where Matlab searches for functions using

```
path
```

You will notice, that the most top path (on start up) is a path in your home folder. For Linux this is e.g. `/home/$USER/Documents/MATLAB`. For Windows it is somewhere in the the `c:\Users\%USER%\Documents\Matlab` (I think). Placing a file [startup.m](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) in this folder allows to add additional paths using

```
addpath('H:\MyTeam\Matlab\Misc_Function');
```

or

```
addpath(genpath('H:\MyTeam\Matlab\Misc_Function'));
```

on start up of Matlab. The latter ([genpath](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/genpath.html)) allows to also add all subdirectories. Simply write a file `startup.m` and add one of above lines there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'addpath' will add the folder to MATLAB path only for the current MATLAB session. To save the updated path for other sessions, you need to execute 'savepath' command.

As mentioned in the previous comments, adding the folder in startup.m is a good idea since it will be added to the path on MATLAB startup.

To answer your question about how MATLAB finds the correct function, MATLAB maintains a list of directories in its path in a file called pathdef.m. Any changes to the path will be written to this file (when you execute 'savepath'). The path variable is initialized with the contents of this file.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up editing the pathdef.m file. I just added the directory location in here, and works nicely. I did look at the startup.m file but have to be honest wasn't sure how to add my directory.

Comment: You need to call addpath('directory to add') in startup.m. This way, the directory is added to MATLAB path every time MATLAB starts up.